# Python Panda Dataframe Error while fetching path from .config file

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Trying to create the data frame using  (.config) file to fetch the file but getting error during creation of Dataframe from the below file

**Actual file name:rgf_ltd_060520202**

Sample Structure of my config fil(which is pipe seperated) :

```
...|/user/Doc/ABC/rgf_ltd_[0-9]*|CSV|Collection
```

and from here when I try to create the data frame by fetching my config file in my Script

```
import pandas as pd

#fetching details fromconfig file
with open('config','r') as rd:
   lines=rd.readlies() 
   for line in lines:
       f_path=#fetching my csv file path(/user/Doc/ABC/rgf_ltd_[0-9]*)
```

Above part working file and **/user/Doc/ABC/rgf_ltd_[0-9]*** is also fetched by python script when i pass f_path in read_csv function.

```
#dataframe 
data=pd.read_csv(f_path,sep='|',engine='python')
```

and when I execute the above script interpreter throw an error:

```
No such file or Directory:/user/Doc/ABC/rgf_ltd_[0-9]*
```

I am giving this regex to make my path more **dynamic**.

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas.read_csv` doesn't deal with regex patters on file reading, you could use the python [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) module to get a similar result with shell-style wildcards.

> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which must be a string containing a path specification. pathname can be either absolute (like /usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile) or relative (like ../../Tools/*/*.gif), **and can contain shell-style wildcards**. Broken symlinks are included in the results (as in the shell). Whether or not the results are sorted depends on the file system.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

f_path = os.path.join("user","Doc", "ABC")
f_pattern = "rgf_ltd_[0-9]*"

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(f_path, f_pattern))
print(file_list) # ['user\\Doc\\ABC\\rgf_ltd_3498543058']

# dataframe
data = pd.read_csv(file_list[0], sep='|', engine='python')
print(data)
```

Output from *data*

```
             Col0            Col1            Col2
0  InsideRGF_R0C0  InsideRGF_R0C1  InsideRGF_R0C2
1  InsideRGF_R1C0  InsideRGF_R1C1  InsideRGF_R1C2
2  InsideRGF_R2C0  InsideRGF_R2C1  InsideRGF_R2C2
3  InsideRGF_R3C0  InsideRGF_R3C1  InsideRGF_R3C2
```

Comment: Thank  you @n1colas.m